# How to strip the trailing URL in an nginx 404 redirect?

Tags: redirect, nginx

We have an nginx server running and the default 404 is the generic nginx 404. It's now setup to redirect all pages to the index page using this snippet:

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html
```

Seems to be working well but now on the redirected homepage you see the trailing URL instead of the TLD.

Example:

```
www.somesite.com/whereis404
```

should redirect to

```
www.somesite.com
```

and strip out the

```
/whereis404
```

I'm not sure how to strip out that trailing url, etc on the redirect. Any thoughts or is this not doable in nginx?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the address bar, you need to perform an external redirect. By specifying a relative URI, `nginx` performs an internal redirect by default. There are a number of directives which perform an external redirect, but replacing the URI on the `error_page` directive with a *scheme* and a *host name* will instruct `nginx` to make the redirect external:

```
error_page 404 =200 $scheme://$server_name/;
error_page 404 =200 $scheme://$host/;
```

If you are in a reverse-proxy environment, the second variant would be preferable. This assumes you have an `index` defined, otherwise append `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks Richard for the tips. Tried both and no go on my site. I'm still learning in's and out's of nginx so not sure if I applied these to the conf file properly. I'll re-look at it today and see what happens.

Comment: @Valien I am so sorry. I missed a `:` in my example.

Comment: Yeah, it's redirecting but not stripping out the trailing content. So not sure what I'm doing wrong. Will keep working on it.

Comment: @Valien Make sure you restart `nginx` as it only re-reads config on a restart, and make sure you clear your browser's cache.